# ¿Como hacer redirecciones 301 eficientemente en un sitio multilingüe?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirección, seo

¡Hola!

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de crear redirecciones 301 en el .htaccess de manera eficiente cuando tenemos un sitio multilingüe.

Les muestro un ejemplo práctico. Digamos que tengo una cantidad bastante grande de URLs que he modificado y debo redireccionar:

- https://mi-sitio.com/producto-1/
- https://mi-sitio.com/producto-2/
- https://mi-sitio.com/producto-3/
- 100 URLs más...

Y para redireccionarlas lo que haría seria:

- Redirect 301 /producto-1/ https://mi-sitio.com/producto-con-otro-nombre-1/
- Redirect 301 /producto-2/ https://mi-sitio.com/producto-con-otro-nombre-2/
- Redirect 301 /producto-3/ https://mi-sitio.com/producto-con-otro-nombre-3/
- Y así para todos las 100 URLs más...

Ahora, el problema surge cuando tenemos un sitio multilingüe, ya que de la forma explicada anteriormente, habría que crear un Redirect 301 para cada variante de lenguaje del sitio, por lo que, si tenemos 7 idiomas, las 100 redireciones se multiplican por 7, es decir, 700 líneas de código más en el archivo .htaccess.

El resultado sería algo así:

- Redirect 301 /producto-1/ https://mi-sitio.com/producto-con-otro-nombre-1/
- Redirect 301 /en/producto-1/ https://mi-sitio.com/en/producto-con-otro-nombre-1/
- Redirect 301 /producto-2/ https://mi-sitio.com/producto-con-otro-nombre-2/
- Redirect 301 /en/producto-2/ https://mi-sitio.com/en/producto-con-otro-nombre-2/
- Y así, para cada url y cada variante de idioma.

¿Es posible crear una RewriteRule que utilice un regex con la url que queremos cambiar, y la devuelva con la url a la que queremos redirigir incluyendo el idioma actual?. Algo como esto:

RewriteRule /producto-1/ -> (aquí iría todo lo anterior a /producto-1/ es decir, el dominio + la variante de idioma si tiene) + /producto-con-otro-nombre/

De esta forma, si estoy en la versión en inglés, me redirige a la versión que quiero pero con el idioma que tengo puesto actualmente, y si estoy en otra versión de idioma o sin versión de idioma, me redirige a la versión correspondiente.

De esta manera no habría que declarar una redirección para cada versión de idioma, sino que la misma RewriteRule afecta a todas las versiones de idioma.

Creo que esto es posible pero no consigo entender cómo declarar el RewriteRule para que use un parámetro o lo que pretendo hacer en el ejemplo.

Comment: Que hay detras del .htaccess?  páginas estáticas (html puro) o dinamicas (php/asp/..)?

Comment: Si son dinámicas te recomiendo no usar el .htaccess para la redireccion, sino directamente lo lees desde ellas, que seguramente pasan por un index.php, y alli te montas una tabla con las equivalencias y lo gestionas desde alli, o con expresiones regulares y headers 301. El motivo son varios, pero el más importante es no inundar el .htaccess son tropocientas lineas porque cualquier visita tendra que pasar por alli y ralentizará su entrada.

Comment: En principio lo planteo para páginas dinámicas, en concreto, en el ejemplo que dice, fue un caso similar que tuve que afrontar en WordPress.